# Azure elastic query (external datasoruce) and entity framework code-first

Tags: entity-framework, azure, azure-sql-database

We are using entity-framework as our ORM. We have several Azure SQL databases, and a need arises for cross-db queries to be performed. Is there a way to create and use Azure Elastic Queries via Entity Framework code first?

Comment: Is it possible to avoid cross-db queries?

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas, so far it seems like the answer is no.

Comment: I've never used Azure Elastic Queries, so I'm trying out. How about using `DbQuery` and creating a view from raw SQL statement? An example can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/query-types).

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas, thanks, I'll have a look. But I think there Azure has issues with cross-db views

Comment: If that does not work out, you might have to use `FromSql()` extension and encapsulate these queries in your repository.

Comment: Do the databases have the same schema?  What is the purpose of using multiple databases?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft, they store related data, I need a join across two databases.

Comment: If they store related data, then what is the purpose of using multiple databases?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft, a design flaw (and a requirement), unfortunatelly there is nothing that can be changed about it right now.